# Can't resolve Services with missing/Available dependencies Wildfly 8.1 and MySQL 5.7 JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed

Tags: mysql, wildfly-8

I'm trying to configure a data source in Wildfly 8.1 with MySQL.  I'm on a local environment on windows and I keep getting errors when I start the server.  The datasource is registered, but fails when i test it.

[image]

I have the mysql connector jar file in C:\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main

standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS" pool-name="MySQLDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookdb</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>*******</password>
                    </security>
                    <timeout>  
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>  
                        <query-timeout>600</query-timeout>  
                    </timeout>                    
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

module.xml     C:\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
     <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"/>              
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>
     <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
     <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

> 00:46:17,927 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation](ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "datasources"), ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql") ]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [com.mysql]"
>
> 00:46:17,912 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
>
> 00:46:18,171 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
>
> 00:46:18,165 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path C:\wildfly/welcome-content
>
> 00:46:18,498 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
>
> 00:46:18,558 INFO [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final
>
> 00:46:18,694 INFO org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly\standalone\deployments
>
> 00:46:18,701 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080
>
> 00:46:18,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
>
> 00:46:19,112 INFO [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.4.Final
>
> 00:46:19,122 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "datasources"), ("data-source" => "MySQLDS") ]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]","jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]" ]}
>
> 00:46:19,155 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "datasources"),("data-source" => "MySQLDS") ]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]","jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"],"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {"Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.data-source.reference-factory.MySQLDS", "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MySQLDS"], "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"] } }
>
> 00:46:19,254 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS, service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS]
>
> 00:46:19,616 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
>
> 00:46:19,628 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
>
> 00:46:19,643 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" started (with errors) in 4876ms - Started 185 of 238 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 81 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
>
> 00:51:40,780 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation](management-handler-thread - 4) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([ ("subsystem" => "datasources"), ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql-5-driver") ]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [mysql]"
>
> 00:51:47,961 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation](management-handler-thread - 6) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "datasources"), ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql-5-driver") ]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [mysql]"
>
> 00:53:21,929 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation](management-handler-thread - 8) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "datasources"), ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql-5-driver") ]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [com.mysql]"
>
> 01:01:49,324 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation](XNIO-1 task-7) JBAS014613: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "datasources"), ("data-source" => "MySQLDS") ]) - failure description: "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010442: failed to match pool. Check JndiName: java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the MySQL connector .jar file via the browser console as a deployment fixed the issue.

[image: WildFly Console]

My data source is working in WildFly 10x, so I don't know if there was an issue with version 8.1.

Here's a decent video on 3 ways to add a data source to Wildfly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSHXMcRsF0A